# "Device calibration" or "calibration of a device"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, possessives, sentence-choice

I need to know how to specify something in English, I mean for example in the following case:

> "Device calibration" or "calibration of a device"?

How can I know which is the right one?

What is the difference?

What rule I have to follow?

Is the structure of the second one used just to express possession?

Answer (score 3):

*Please note that this answer was provided before any edits were made to the OP's question.*

---

Lambie's right that this is a complicated question.  He's not quite right about the issue of posession.  You need to ask yourself, "what am I talking about?  A state or condition of the device, or an action that affects the device?"  Are you using the word as an adjective or a noun?

**Used as an adjective: Possessive**

> The calibration of the device => The device's calibration

We are talking about a condition of the device: the fact that because it has been calibrated it is now in a calibrated state.  We're using *calibration* as an adjective to describe the state of the device.

**Used as a noun: Compound noun**

> The calibration of a device<sup>1</sup> => Device calibration

In this example we're talking about something that can be *done to* a device — the act of calibrating the device.  This uses *calibration* as a noun identifying the action.  Because we want to be specific about what we're calibrating, we use a compound noun: "device calibration."

Here are examples of the two uses:

> I'll do the device calibration. (a task is being completed)
>
> I'll change the device's calibration. (a condition of the device is changing)

**Conclusion**

So, you need to decide if you're using *calibrate* as an adjective or a noun.  If it's an adjective, you'll use the posessive forms.  If you're using it as a noun, you use the compound noun forms.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Please note that I am skipping the discussion of "a device's calibtration" vs. "the device's calibration."  That might be a diservice to you.  The magic isn't "a" vs. "the."  The magic is choosing what you're talking about: adjective or noun.  I felt that pointing this out in a footnote would be more clear than trying to discuss it in the body of my answer.  Thanks!*

Comment: Can I also use it for 2 terms? Such as "Implementation of shop and laboratory motor pool"? Thanks!

Comment: The calibration of the device being made into device calibration is not possessive. It's creating compound nouns from A of B, which is not: John's house, which is a possessive.

Comment: @Lambie, I'm afraid you've missed my point: it can be.  It depends on how you're using the word.  If "calibration" is used as an adjective, it uses the posessive form.  If it is used as a noun, it uses the noun form.  I'll make that more clear in my answer.

Comment: @JBH No, you have missed mine. Not everything that is **of** is a possessive. John's car is a possessive. My car uses a possessive pronoun. calibration of a device and device calibration are not possessives at all.

Comment: @Lambie, I agree that the OP had that confusion, which is why I explained it all.  "Device calibration" is a compound noun identifying an action.  "Device's calibration" is a possessive describing a condition of a device.  I suspect we are enjoying what a colleague of mine once described as "violent agreement."  We're both vociferously describing the same aspect of the OP's question from different perspectives.  Would you agree?